# How should I free up space in /boot to install latest kernal

Tags: boot, server, kernel, root

First, I want to get rid of this message :

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-4.4-latest : Depends: linux-image-4.4.154-111-rockchip-g39b306a41b2d but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

then I want to free up /boot/

this command does tell me what can be removed:

```
root@rockpi:/boot# sudo dpkg --list 'linux-image*'|awk '{ if ($1=="ii") print $2}'|grep -v `uname -r`
linux-image-4.4.154-59-rockchip-g5e70f14
linux-image-4.4.154-95-rockchip-gd2ab1f26e1b3
```

currently boot contains:

```
/boot# ll
total 72698
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root    16384 Oct 10 21:17 ./
drwxr-xr-x 25 root root     4096 Aug 13 18:46 ../
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  4786387 Jun 22 07:37 System.map-4.4.154-110-rockchip-gcef30e88a9f5*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  4707224 Dec 14  2018 System.map-4.4.154-59-rockchip-g5e70f14*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  4567572 Oct 21  2019 System.map-4.4.154-95-rockchip-gd2ab1f26e1b3*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root       42 Jul 27 20:34 cmdline.txt*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   155639 Jun 22 07:37 config-4.4.154-110-rockchip-gcef30e88a9f5*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   152995 Dec 14  2018 config-4.4.154-59-rockchip-g5e70f14*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   155489 Oct 21  2019 config-4.4.154-95-rockchip-gd2ab1f26e1b3*
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root     2048 Oct 10 21:17 dtbs/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     2048 Oct 10 21:17 extlinux/
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     1807 Oct 21  2019 hw_intfc.conf*
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     2048 Nov 19  2019 overlays/
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 20371464 Jun 22 07:37 vmlinuz-4.4.154-110-rockchip-gcef30e88a9f5*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 20006920 Dec 14  2018 vmlinuz-4.4.154-59-rockchip-g5e70f14*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 19496968 Oct 21  2019 vmlinuz-4.4.154-95-rockchip-gd2ab1f26e1b3*
```

my final objective is to update to latest kernal

```
 $ sudo apt-get install -y linux-4.4-latest # Will update kernel
```

please help.

Comment: have you run `sudo apt autoremove`? This will remove old, unused kernels

Comment: i solved it by removing `linux-4.4-latest` first .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I free up more space in /boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot)

Comment: I have solved that see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

my /boot partition was 100% full.

and I had previously attempted to install latest-linux kernal but its dependency was unmet because no space in /boot.

so first I removed `linux-4.4-latest`
`sudo apt purge linux-4.4-latest`
this got me rid of umet dependency error making way to execute the below purge commands successfully

the I ran `sudo dpkg --list 'linux-image*'|awk '{ if ($1=="ii") print $2}'|grep -v`uname -r` to find out what more can be removed

> some old linux-kernel

then I ran `sudo apt purge old-linux-kernel`

this made extra space then I finally ran

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

which got rid of few more kbs of data and I was able to update to latest linux kernal.